# Thrift service doesn't show any method to invoke

Tags: java, web-services, apache, thrift

I have created my first Web Service through Apache Thrift. I am deploying it on a Tomcat using Maven and Apache CXF.

Thrift created two classes for me:

- Entry.class
- Guestbook.class

I am implementing the `Guestbook.Iface` in my own `GuestbookService.class`.

On my beans.xml I add the class as an endpoint:

```
<jaxws:endpoint 
  id="guestbook" 
  implementor="guestbook.GuestbookService" 
  address="/guestbook" />
```

When I visit the URL on Tomcat the WSDL does not contain any methods to invoke. It should have `getGuestbookEntries()` already.

1. Is there something I am missing?
2. Am I adding the right class to the endpoint? I realized there is a `Guestbook.Processor` internal class.

I am getting the following response when visiting `http://localhost:8080/thriftGuestbook/guestbook`:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>
No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.
</faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit puzzled since SOAP/WSDL on one hand and Thrift on the other hand do not have that much in common, except they're both technologies that can be used to create web services. Typically you want to use Thrift's own http server. I'm not sure how to do that in your scenario, but SOAP/WSDL is for sure the wrong way using Thrift.

However, if you are absolutely forced to provide a SOAP service, you either can't use Thrift at all, or you have to implement a dual interface which supports both options and where the clients can pick their preferred kind of interface.

But be warned, I would not recommend the latter if you don't have at least some clues what you are doing. A dual interface will require some interesting architectural decisions and a lot more work, especially when more complex data structures come into play. If you have doubts whether it will help to solve your actual problem, then it is most likely the wrong solution. But it is possible (been there, done that).